# Showing that the exterior derivative of a 1-form is 0.

Tags: differential-forms

The question is  $$ Let\quad f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$$
$$\omega = f(||\mathbf x||)(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}dx_{i}) \in \mathcal A^1(\Bbb R^n) $$

$ (a) $ Assuming f is differentiable, prove that $d\omega = 0$ on $\Bbb R^n - \mathbf {0}$.

$(b) $ Assuming f is continuous, prove that $\omega$ is exact.

[image: My work in solving part (a)]

I'm not too sure if this is right, I'm mostly confused by the space $\mathcal A^1(\Bbb R^n)$ and how the partial derivatives will evaluate. Also once I show $d\omega = 0$, how do I show $\omega$ is exact ?

Edit: I'd like to understand the space $\mathcal A^1(\Bbb R^n)$ so I can show that it is simply connected.

Comment: Well one way to know that $\omega$ is exact is by the Poincare lemma, which says that every closed form (which is what you are verifying) is exact on a simply connected domain, which $\mathbb R^n$ is.

Comment: Ah okay, do you know how to show: $${\partial f \over \partial x_i} - {\partial f \over \partial x_j} = 0 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice with your definition of $g$:
$$ \partial_i g_j = x_j \partial_i f( ||x| |) = x_j f'( ||x|| ) \partial_i ||x||= \frac{ x_j x_i }{ ||x||} f'(||x||)$$
(remember $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$)Thus
$$ \partial_i g_j - \partial_j g_i = 0$$
thats the only step  I'd say you missed to justify in a). 
For b), define
$$ \eta = \int_{x_0}^x \omega $$
where the integral is any path from $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What is $d \eta$?